# Set date to last day of previous month in Oracle if it's not the last row

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, lead

Whole setup on SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1fd0e/5

I have some data containing persons id, level and the levels date range like shown below:

```
   PID        LVL START_DATE END_DATE
```

---

```
     1          1 01.01.14   19.03.14 
     1          2 20.03.14   15.08.14 
     1          3 16.08.14   09.10.14 
     1          4 10.10.14   31.12.14 
     2          1 01.01.14   31.12.14 
     3          1 01.01.14   16.01.14
```

I need to set the start date to the first day of month and the end date to the last day of month. the last day rule applies only **if it ist not the last row of data for that person**.

what i've don so far:

```
select
pid, lvl, 
trunc(start_date, 'month') as start_date,
case when lead(pid, 1) over (PARTITION BY pid order by end_date) is not null 
     then last_day(add_months(end_date, -1)) 
     else last_day(end_date) 
     end as end_date
from date_tbl t;
```

gives me the desired output:

```
   PID        LVL START_DATE END_DATE
```

---

```
     1          1 01.01.14   28.02.14 
     1          2 01.03.14   31.07.14 
     1          3 01.08.14   30.09.14 
     1          4 01.10.14   31.12.14 
     2          1 01.01.14   31.12.14 
     3          1 01.01.14   31.01.14
```

**BUT:** It just works well with my test-data. On my production data on a table containing 25k+ rows of data (witch is not too much data i'd say) it performs really slow.

Can anyone give me a hint how I could improve the query's performance? What indices to set on wich columns for example...? The only indexed column so far is the PID column.

Comment: How slow is "really slow"?  And what is the full query?  Since there are 25K rows I assume they are not all just displayed on a screen.  Is there an `UPDATE` statement, or is there a predicate to limit the results for a specific person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, sorry for waisting your time. To make it short: it was my fault. In my procedure the query above makes a LEFT JOIN to another table in some subquery:

```
with dates as (
  select
  pid, lvl, 
  trunc(start_date, 'month') as start_date,
  case when lead(pid, 1) over (PARTITION BY pid order by end_date) is not null 
       then last_day(add_months(end_date, -1)) 
       else last_day(end_date) 
       end as end_date
  from date_tbl t
),
  some_other_table as (
  select pid, (...some more columns)
  from other_table
)
select * from (
  select 
    b.pid,  -- <== this has to be a.pid. b is much bigger than a!
    a.start_date, 
    a.end_date
  from dates a left join some_other_table b on a.pid = b.pid
)
```

The whole query is much bigger.

@jonearles 
thx for your comment. "And what is the full query?" helped me to get back on track: split the query into pieces and check again what REALLY slows it down.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as I understand, your script produces wrong result if person has only one record (case with pid = 3)

Please, could you try this one?

```
select
  pid, 
  lvl, 
  trunc(start_date, 'month') as start_date,
  last_day(add_months(end_date, case when lvl = max(lvl) over (partition by pid) then 0 else -1 end)) end_date
from date_tbl t;
```

I guess that you need to build index for columns (pid, lvl desc)

Comment: thx for answer. the pid 3 record ist correct: it is valid for one month only. the records have to be monthly valid.